# How to display milliseconds in php using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

How can I show the milliseconds of my data from my mysql database to my php file? My table `humidity` has a field named `time` which is currently in `TimeStamp(3)` type. The problem is that the millisecond showing in the table is "000" instead of the real value inside the database.

This is my php code:

```
<?php echo date("g:i:s:v a F j, Y ", strtotime($row['setTime'])); ?>
```

...but it only shows `1:40:45.000 am April 25, 2018` instead of `01:40:45.231 am April 25,2018`.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: `strtotime` returns an integer, representing a number of seconds. If you're passing it something with millisecond granularity, then that information is going to get lost.

Comment: Before MySQL 5.6.4, fractional seconds are *not* stored in column of datatype `TIMESTAMP(3)`. Values supplied can have fractional seconds, the fractional seconds are accepted, but get discarded when the value is stored in table.

Comment: @Uueerdo how do I check that? I am using Xampp v3.2.2 with php 7.2.2 Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id:

Comment: @iainn what is the best way to display the timestamp with milliseconds?

Comment: use PHP DateTime class ... http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @TheodoreFlores `SELECT version()`

Comment: @Uueerdo 10.1.29-MariaDB this one

Comment: That should be fine, just thought it best to cover the possibility you were using an earlier version of MySQL that did not store fractional seconds.

Comment: @Uueerdo how can I migrate my database with its data to a higher version of MySQL?

Comment: You should not need to; if you were on MySQL 5.5 or lower, fractional seconds would not be stored. From what I could tell with cursory research, MariaDB has saved that information since well before the version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php's DateTime [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.  Simply instantiate the class using your timestamp with milliseconds and format it in the same way:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($row['setTime']);
$formatted = $dateTime->format("g:i:s:v a F j, Y");
```

Assuming `$row['setTime'] == '2018-04-25 01:40:45.231'` this would output:

```
1:40:45:231 am April 25, 2018
```

Comment: how do I do that? i tried this `  $dateTime = new DateTime($row['setTime']);
$formatted = $dateTime->format("g:i:s:v a F j, Y");` and `echo $row[$formatted];`

Comment: but theres an error that says undefined index:1:40:45:231

Comment: its all good now thank you very much you are the answer I needed for hours. This means very much to me, thank you very much! have a good day!!!